# Sort causing massive slow-down

Tags: mysql

I have a commenting system I'm developing that I have asked another question about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30779887/count-rows-from-different-tables-in-join-statement). The schema is pretty much the same except I have added a `rating` column in the `comments` table and have set up a trigger to update it when there's changes in the `comments_ratings` table in order to avoid calculating the rating every time I need to fetch comments.

So when I execute my query to fetch the latest comments:

```
SELECT
    c.*, COALESCE (COUNT(r.id), 0) AS replies
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            ...
        FROM 
            comments c
        LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = c.author
        LEFT JOIN comments_ratings crv ON crv.COMMENT = c.id
        AND crv.USER = ?

        WHERE
            c.item = ?
        AND c.type = ?
        ORDER BY
            c.id DESC
        LIMIT 0,
        10
    ) AS c
LEFT JOIN comments r ON c.id = r.reply
GROUP BY
    c.id
ORDER BY
    c.id DESC
```

I get a result back in a matter of 0.001 ~ 0.003 seconds, and I can confirm cache is not helping me because I have tried limiting by random values and the time is always in this range.

However if I try to order by `rating` instead of `c.id`, the query takes 30+ seconds (I have a lot of test data). When I open up the profiler I see that more than 90% of the time it has used for `Copying to tmp table`. I suppose that it is copying the entire table into a in-memory table and sorting it there, but I don't understand why (if) that's happening since I have created an index on column `rating` which *should* help?

The reason I broke database normalization and created the `rating` column instead of calculating it was to be able to index it in order to ease sorting.

I am pretty confused at this point, do you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When you say: "I try to order by rating instead of c.id", do you mean the inner select or the outer one?

Comment: @Renzo The inner one, the outer only sorts a small amount of records so it doesn't influence, practically

Comment: Mysql performs sorting by index with a set on conditions. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html What is the output of `explain` for the inner query?

Comment: @AleksandrK.I will be updating the question with the explain output in a few hours because I don't have access to my dev server right now.

Comment: `Assumption`: you have index on your `id` column and your `rating` column. `Fact`: MySQL can __not__ use more than one index in context of different _`WHERE / ORDER BY / GROUP BY`_ clauses (except rare case of index merging which is not your case). It decided to use `id` index for grouping. Therefore, when ordering by another column, query invokes MySQL mechanism of non-indexed sorting which leads to filesort and, futhermore, copying to temporary storage

Comment: @AlmaDo That is exactly the case, I remember there was `Using filesort` under `extra` on 2 tables in `EXPLAIN`. What would be the solution to this problem?

Comment: Redesign your data model according to your application needs seems to be the most appropriate solution

Comment: @AlmaDo Actually I just removed the grouping from the inner query (seems like I don't even need it after I have moved the join on `r` to the tmp table) and it is now sorting them in a snap!